# Unable to draw google chart through java controller

Tags: ajax, jsp, charts

Hi I am using below Ajax code to access my java controller which helps populate values in another jsp to display google charts with values from database. But the chart doesnt load on the main page, though can be viewed if opened seperately. I think there are issues with the google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); function. Please let me know where/how can i make changes fr it to work.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Controller?action=FoodList",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: The problem lies in the value of request.getContextPath()%>/Controller?action=FoodList, which you are not including in your question.

Comment: the GET url perfectly translates to the jsp that holds logic to get values from database and populate the google chart *Verified by view source and could see the variables in drawchart() getting populated*

Comment: You're asking people to debug the chart, but all you show is an AJAX handler. How can anyone deduce the problem with what you've provided?